# Functions - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am having difficulty when trying to bring a function back to the start of itself. My code is:

```
def questionFour():
    print("")
    global questionsCorrect
    global questionsIncorrect
    print ("What is 4 + 4?")
    questionFour = input (">> ")
    if str.isdigit(questionFour):
        if questionFour.lower() == ("8"):
            questionsCorrect += 1
            questionFive()
        else:
            questionsIncorrect += 1
            questionFive()
    else:
        print ("That's not a number!")
        questionFour()
```

I am getting this issue:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[hidden]", line 330, in <module>
    questionOne()
  File "[hidden]", line 42, in questionOne
    questionTwo()
  File "[hidden]", line 53, in questionTwo
    questionThree()
  File "[hidden]", line 70, in questionThree
    questionFour()
  File "[hidden]", line 87, in questionFour
    questionFour()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Thanks!

Comment: `questionFour()`->`questionFour`

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* so we can see what line caused this and how Python got there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assigning to questionFour with the line `questionFour = input ...`. Because of Python's scoping, this will only remain true inside of the function, but renders you unable to call it recursively. Choose a different variable name for the input.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to accept the answer when Stack Exchange lets you.